# How to auto fill in react material table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am trying to do something like auto fill rowData.properties on material table. But props.value always is undefined. Thisis my code

```
 <MaterialTable
  title="Simple Action Preview"
  columns={[
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
    { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric'},
    
    {
      title: 'Birth Place',
      field: 'birthCity',
      lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
    },
    {
      title: 'Full name',
      field: 'fullName',
      editComponent: (props)=>{
        return <div onClick={()=> handleClick(props) > // props.value at here always null
        <TextField
            value={`${props.rowData.name} ${props.rowData.surname}`  // fullname with edit component auto fill here
            onChange={(e)=>props.onChange(e.target.value)}
        />
        </div>
      },
      
    }
  ]}
  data={[
    { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 , fullName: 'Mehmet Baran'},
    { name: 'Zerya', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34 , fullName: 'Zerya Baran'},
  ]}        
  actions={[
    {
      icon: 'save',
      tooltip: 'Save User',
      onClick: (event, rowData) => alert("You saved " + rowData.name)
    }
  ]}
/>
```

How to auto fill rowData.fieldName in material table? With fullName is example.
Please help me resolve it

Comment: Can u plz console `props` before return and see whats in there.

Comment: Hi @Neel Dsouza thank you for your inform. That field is auto fill when input ip address entered. I will look like this. [ipAddress: 192.168.1.1] - auto fill [httpUrl: http://192.168.1.1]

But after confirm saved, at here the field httpUrl doesn't enter. At here, I passing callback function and log this props but noticed that value is  a undefine.

Comment: @NeelDsouza can you run sample code at thread? Please help me resolve it. Sorry for my English skills is very bad

Comment: I'll not be able to run the code without proper data coming in props. Can u create a codesandbox so that its better to analyze.

Comment: @NeelDsouza I very gateful with your support, I has resolved it. Thank you